# Ionic 4 Disable iOS Swipe Back in ONE PAGE ONLY

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, swipe, back, ionic-native

I want to disable `iOS` in one page only and not globally, so let’s say a user checkouts and makes the payment, i don’t want the user to go back to where he was after he gets the receipt. I want the user to stay to that page without the possibility to swipe back, in android i have already disabled the hardware button while in `iOS` i am struggling a bit.

i have added to **app.module:**

```
IonicModule.forRoot({ swipeBackEnabled: false })
```

which disables the swipe back globally and thats what i don’t want, i also **tried this one:**

[Article about disabling swipe back](https://www.damirscorner.com/blog/posts/20190823-SwipebackGestureConfigurationInIonic4.html)

I followed it and still i could not reach what i want,

I also don’t get what the user says at the end:

The current **implementation** only works with a single `IonRouterInstance` in the application but it can be enhanced with support for additional instances if you require that in your own application.

What does he mean by **WORKS WITH A SINGLE?**

Thank you very much, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer can be found in ionic forum [HERE](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-4-disable-ios-swipe-back-in-one-page-only/180464/2)

Answer (score 6):

Inject `IonRouterOutlet` into your class:

```js
constructor(private routerOutlet: IonRouterOutlet) {}
```

Deactivate swipe gesture where you want (typically in `ngOnInit` or `ionViewDidEnter`):

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.routerOutlet.swipeGesture = false;
}
```

Activate it again when you need it (typically in `ionViewWillLeave` or `ionViewDidLeave`):

```js
ionViewWillLeave() {
    this.routerOutlet.swipeGesture = true;
}
```

Did it help you? Help me back with an upvote.

Comment: Not sure, but this isn't working with Ionic 5