# Ionic 6 capacitor disable back swipe on a particular page

Tags: capacitor, ionic6

Looking to disable users from swiping back to the login page. I am using ionic 6 and capacitor

I am using:

```
    import { IonRouterOutlet } from '@ionic/angular';



    constructor(private routerOutlet: IonRouterOutlet) {
    }



    ngOnInit() {
      this.routerOutlet.swipeGesture = false;
    }
```

Having no effect.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59863311/20009330

works

dont forget to implement all the code