# Ionic 7 Angular 16 Cant disable swipe menu on single pages

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

i have 3 pages that i want to disable the swipe menu for.  i have entered the following code in all three pages but i can still swipe right to open the menu. any have ideas what im doing wrong?

```
 ionViewDidEnter(): void {
    this.menu.close().then(() => {   
      this.menu.enable(false).then(() => {
        this.menu.swipeGesture(false)
      }); 
    }); 
  }

  ionViewDidLeave(): void {
    this.menu.close().then(() => {   
      this.menu.enable(true).then(() => {
        this.menu.swipeGesture(true)
      }); 
    }); 
  }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59499542/ionic-4-disable-ios-swipe-back-in-one-page-only

this works for the whole page. it might help you. dont forget to implement all the pages.